# Yosemite 10.10.3 has no Photos app

Tags: macos, photos

Here's a strange one. I have Yosemite 10.10.3 and no updates required but don't seem to have Photos app. Any suggestions as to how I might get it?

Comment: Please be more specific. What have you tried, what are your suggestions, what is your before experience of photos app (if any)

Comment: It should be included as part of the 10.10.3 update.

Try downloading the combo updater & see if that will add it - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804?

Comment: @ TheBro21 I had Iphoto before. I updated to Yosemite and then iphoto stopped working. When I clicked on it, I was sent to the app store, that said iphoto not available for Yosemite in the Uk. I surfed around and discovered I should have the new Photos app instead, which I don't have.

Comment: iPhoto still works under 10.10.3 - it is just no longer supported & will not be updated. It's sounding even more like something went wrong with the update

Comment: I'll cobble together an answer for future Googlers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Photos is supposed to be included in the 10.10.3 update automatically, I would suspect something may have gone wrong with the OS update itself.

In cases like this, I would always try downloading the current combo updater from Apple - currently 10.10.3 from https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804 but you can always Google for "Apple combo updater [current number]" to find the latest.

The combo updater, unlike the regular delta updater, includes all changes since the last major update, in this case 10.10.0

I would also run Disk Utility & check permissions & drive integrity - before & after running the combo, just to be certain.